# How do I to get a Raspberry Pi IRC server to work?

Tags: server, networking, irc

I am trying to set up an IRC server with services on my Raspberry Pi. I googled around and decided on using hybrid-ircd for the server and hybserv for the services (nickserv, chanserv, etc.).

So far, I have managed to set up a functioning bare bones server, and I installed and configured hybserv. The problem is that I cannot get hybserv to work with hybrid. On XChat I get:

```
*** Notice -- Link [unknown@127.0.0.1] introduced server with bogus server ID
```

and using `sudo tail -f /var/log/ircd/hybserv.log` I get:

```
Sun Mar  6 17:15:20 2016 Connecting to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] tcp/6667
Sun Mar  6 17:15:20 2016 Connected to 127.0.0.1 tcp/6667
Sun Mar  6 17:15:20 2016 Server Error: Bogus server ID introduced
Sun Mar  6 17:15:20 2016 Server Error: Closing Link: localhost (Bogus server ID introduced)
```

I have searched all round and found nothing on this exact error and nothing to fix it. I have done a reinstall of hybserv and it did not help.

Here is my `connect{}` block in `/etc/ircd-hybrid/ircd.conf`:

```
connect {
        /* name: the name of the server */
        name = "irc.example.net";

        /* host: the host or IP address to connect to. If a hostname is used it
         * must match the reverse DNS of the server.
         */
        host = "127.0.0.1";

        /* Passwords: the passwords we send (OLD C:) and accept (OLD N:).
         * The remote server will have these passwords reversed.
         */
        send_password = "password";
        accept_password = "password";

        /* compressed: controls whether traffic is compressed via ziplinks.
         * By default this is disabled
         */
        compressed = no;
};
```

And here is my `/etc/hybserv/hybserv.conf`:

```
O:*@*:mypassword:root:segj
A:Debian User <anemail@gmail.com>
N:irc.example.net:Hybrid services
S:password:127.0.0.1
V:127.0.0.1
C:#services
I:*.blah.com:6:1
```

At this point I am completely stumped as to how to fix this.

I am doing this on a Raspberry Pi (B+).

P.S:

I am using `2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie`, `hybrid-1:8.2.0+dfsg.1-2+deb8u1`, and `Hybserv2 TS services version 1.9.5-release`.

I used [this tutorial](http://www.the-tech-tutorial.com/setting-up-an-basic-irc-server-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hybserv Services project has abandoned development long time ago, as they also have mentioned on their github project's site. So basically Hybserv is outdated and the protocol is no longer compatible with modern ircd-hybrid.

From what I have read on [www.ircd-hybrid.org](http://www.ircd-hybrid.org/), the Anope IRC services is the recommended IRC services package for use with ircd-hybrid.

Comment: From [Github - hybserv2](https://github.com/dkorunic/hybserv2): `Important note: as it currently stands, Hybserv2 is incompatible with IRCD Hybrid 8.x as they have decided to be TS3 incompatible.`, although it also says: `Hybserv2 is a new and improved version of the now unsupported Hybserv, sporting new features, bugfixes, and more.`

Answer (score 0):

@Greenonline: you should post the full context:

> " Important note: as it currently stands, Hybserv2 is incompatible
>   with IRCD Hybrid 8.x as they have decided to be TS3 incompatible.
>   There is some grunt work needed to make it fully TS6 and I personally
>   don't have any more time and interest to code for IRC and related to
>   IRC. For me, IRC has long died, as well as NNTP and other things we
>   Unix kids loved in the past. "